# How to convert the PathBuf to String

Tags: string, rust, directory, path

I have to convert the `PathBuf` variable to a `String` to feed my function. My code is like this:

```
let cwd = env::current_dir().unwrap();
let my_str: String = cwd.as_os_str().to_str().unwrap().to_string();
println!("{:?}", my_str);
```

it works but is awful with the `cwd.as_os_str…`.
Do you have a more convenient method or any suggestions on how to handle it?

Answer (score 94):

As mcarton has already said it is not so simple as not all paths are [UTF-8 encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). But you can use:

```
p.into_os_string().into_string()
```

In order to have a fine control of it utilize `?` to send error to upper level or simply ignore it by calling `unwrap()`:

```
let my_str = cwd.into_os_string().into_string().unwrap();
```

A nice thing about `into_string()` is that the error wrap the original `OsString` value.

Answer (score 38):

It is not easy on purpose: `String` are UTF-8 encoded, but `PathBuf` might not be (eg. on Windows). So the conversion might fail.

There are also [`to_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#method.to_str) and [`to_string_lossy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#method.to_string_lossy) methods for convenience. The former returns an `Option<&str>` to indicate possible failure and the later will always succeed but will replace non-UTF-8 characters with `U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER` (which is why it returns `Cow<str>`: if the path is already valid UTF-8, it will return a reference to the inner buffer but if some characters are to be replaced, it will allocate a new `String` for that; in both case you can then use [`into_owned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/collections/borrow/enum.Cow.html#method.into_owned) if you really need a `String`).

Comment: Could you add a short explanation about `Cow` and the hint to use `into_owned()`? Or may I edit your answer to add it?

Comment: Thank you very much. @lukas kalbertodt, for the usage of Cow, you can refer to this blog: http://hermanradtke.com/2015/05/29/creating-a-rust-function-that-returns-string-or-str.html

Answer (score 30):

One way to convert PathBuf to String would be:

`your_path.as_path().display().to_string();`

Comment: I've been using this because it is convenient.  Do you know if it uses to_string_lossy() internally?   Otherwise, I wonder how it does the conversion without returning any possible error?

Comment: The `.as_path()` method is not necessary per the documentation: "It also implements `Deref` to `Path`, meaning that all methods on `Path` slices are available on `PathBuf` values as well."

Comment: this works vety good

Answer (score 6):

As [@mcarton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2733851/mcarton) mentioned, to_string_lossy() should do the job.

```
let cwd = env::current_dir().unwrap();
let path: String =String::from(cwd.to_string_lossy());

rustc 1.56.1 (59eed8a2a 2021-11-01)
```

I am a (learning) Rust fan (years of c/c++ programmer) but man, if it makes simple thing so complicated, UTF-8 and COW.. makes people lost in the translation.

Comment: `Path.to_string_lossy()` is the best answer so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The shortest solution, which also takes Unicode characters into account, as necessary for Windows paths:

```
let my_str: String = cwd.display().to_string();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=2115d57be684ad062fdfe64ce637dee4)