# Can I use `std::path::Path`'s `strip_prefix` to replace a dynamic prefix?

Tags: path, rust

The reason I'm interested in doing this is because there's a part of my path which will remain constant but which I wish to remove along with all its parent pieces.

So if we have say,

```
some/unknown/path/foo/bar/baz
```

I would like to return

```
bar/baz
```

But with the expectation that I only know `foo/...` directly proceeds the part of the path I care about.

Perhaps `strip_prefix` is the wrong approach so if there's a better way of doing this I would certainly appreciate being pointed in that direction.

Comment: Do you want to return a `Path` like `strip_prefix` does, or is it OK to build a new `PathBuf` and return that?

Comment: Ultimately I need a `String`--so it's okay to return `PathBuf` if that'll get us there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`strip_prefix` won't do what you want, because it requires that you know the prefix to strip. However, you can use [`iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.iter) to get an iterator over path components, and then use standard `Iterator` methods to build a new `PathBuf` out of only the part you want.

Here's an example ([try it](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f466731b3a97bbcb2d901b9092881e86&version=stable&mode=debug)):

```
let p = path::Path::new("some/unknown/path/foo/bar/baz");
let q: path::PathBuf = p.iter()   // iterate over path components
    .skip_while(|s| *s != "foo")  // skip everything before "foo"
    .skip(1)                      // skip "foo" itself
    .collect();                   // collect the rest into a PathBuf
println!("{:?}", q); // prints "bar/baz"
```

(This will allocate a new `PathBuf`. [Shepmaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50110652/3650362) shows how to get a `&Path` referencing the original without allocating.)

You can then use [`to_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#method.to_str), [`to_string_lossy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#method.to_string_lossy), or [`into_os_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#method.into_os_string) plus [`OsString::into_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.OsString.html#method.into_string) to get something that can be turned into a `String`.

See also: [How to convert the PathBuf to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37388107/how-to-convert-the-pathbuf-to-string)

Answer (score 4):

While I think that [trentcl's answer is cleaner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50110298/155423), it's worth showing some non-allocating versions.

#### Using `Path::strip_prefix`

To use [`Path::strip_prefix`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.strip_prefix), you need to know the prefix. We can generate it by walking up the [`parent`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.parent)s of the original path until we find one that [`ends_with`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.ends_with) "foo".

```
use std::path::Path;

fn thing1<P>(path: &P) -> Result<&Path, ()>
where
    P: AsRef<Path> + ?Sized,
{
    let original = path.as_ref();
    let mut prefix = original;

    while !prefix.ends_with("foo") {
        prefix = match prefix.parent() {
            Some(p) => p,
            None => return Err(()),
        };
    }

    original.strip_prefix(prefix).map_err(|_| ())
}

fn main() {
    let x = thing1("some/unknown/path/foo/bar/baz");
    println!("{:?}", x);
}
```

#### With an iterator

We can [iterate](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.iter) over the pieces of the path, [taking values while](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take_while) it's not "foo". Once we've advanced the iterator enough, we can get the remainder [as a path](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Iter.html#method.as_path).

```
use std::path::Path;

fn thing2<P>(path: &P) -> &Path
where
    P: AsRef<Path> + ?Sized,
{
    let path = path.as_ref();
    let mut i = path.iter();

    for _ in i.by_ref().take_while(|c| *c != "foo") {}

    i.as_path()
}

fn main() {
    let x = thing2("some/unknown/path/foo/bar/baz");
    println!("{:?}", x);
}
```

This returns an empty path when "foo" doesn't exist.