# What is the best way to use PathBuf in a command call in Rust?

Tags: string, rust, path

```rust
Command::new(format!("git -C {} status", dir.as_path().display().to_string()));
```

I'm using the code above which [converts my `PathBuf` variable to a `String`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61142928/12069968), but is this the best way?  Is there a method to use the `PathBuf` variable without converting it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you're concerned about the `PathBuf` to `String` conversion in the scenario where `PathBuf` is not valid UTF-8. If that's the case I'd refactor that line into its own function and manually construct an `OsString` to create the `Command`:

```rust
use std::ffi::OsString;
use std::path::PathBuf;
use std::process::Command;

fn git_status(dir: PathBuf) -> Command {
    let mut os_string: OsString = "git -C ".into();
    os_string.push(&dir);
    os_string.push(" status");
    Command::new(os_string)
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b84c643f868c81362745f7144db05c66)

Comment: Thank you for this.  This is good.  The only reason I am using PathBuf here is because what I am dealing with are paths... But if I am going to convert to string anyway, would you recommend having them as a string to begin with?

Comment: If all your paths are going to be valid UTF-8 and you won't need use any Path specific methods then sure, there's nothing wrong with using a String in that case.

Answer (score 7):

Your example runs the executable `git -C $dir status` passing no arguments to that executable. It will error as soon as you `spawn()`, because such an oddly named file is not in your `PATH`.

Instead, run `git` passing your arguments:

```
Command::new("git").arg("-C").arg(dir).arg("status")
```

It also makes the question moot because there is no transformation necessary.

Comment: You're absolutely right.  I have accepted @pretzelhammer's answer as the "correct" solution assuming my original question wasn't flawed, but this is the correct (only?) way to do this.  Thank you.